# Counting occurence of a table of values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got a table (Countries) which only contains 1 column (Country).
I've got a table (Essays) which has several columns, though I'm only interested in the "RawText" column.

I can readily run the following:

```
select count(Id) Occurences
from Essays
where Essays.RawText like '%canada%';
```

I'd like to be able to run 1 query that iterates through the long list of countries.

Ideally I'd be able to return a table such as:

```
Canada 10
USA    45
Mexico 39
```

...

How do I go about searching for all the countries?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for a Group By.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get every combination of essay and country, join both tables together. The LIKE pattern can be constructed from the country name; in SQL, string concatenation is `||`. To aggregate the search results, use grouping.

```
SELECT Country,
       COUNT(*)
FROM Countries
JOIN Essays ON RawText LIKE '%' || Country || '%'
GROUP BY Country;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `GROUP BY` to count entries by a distinct column type, but you'll need to take the extra step of 'binning' your search into distinct phrases using a `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    RawText
FROM
    Essays
WHERE
    (Essays.RawText ILIKE '%canada%') OR (Essays.RawText ILIKE '%USA%')
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN Essays.RawText LIKE '%canada%' THEN 'canada'
        WHEN Essays.RawText LIKE '%USA%' THEN 'USA'
        ELSE NULL
    END
```

Comment: And what happens when an essay mentions both countries?

Comment: The real problem here is that there are a lot of countries (not just the 3 in my example), way too much work to bin them all, and then trying to keep track of additions or subtractions would be problematic.